# UTF-8 in .htaccess doesn't have effect if the URL ends in /

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, utf-8, character-encoding

I've created a `.htaccess` file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

So that my HTML heading

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'>
```

will be respected. However, it only works if I specify `/index.html` in the end of the URL. If I don't (and use only `http://www.example.com/`), it doesn't work.

I know I can use `AddDefaultCharset`, or specify multiple extensions for `AddCharset` directives, but how do I specify the total lack of a filename?

Comment: *"So that my HTML heading ... will be respected"*…? FYI, if you set an HTTP Content-Type header, then the HTML `<meta>` tag will be *ignored*, because the information is already in the HTTP header.

Comment: @deceze Right. I first thought it was the opposite, that's why all my HTML pages use a `<meta>` tag for charset. Now that my new server uses ISO-8859-1, I've found out that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve the problem, I've added the following lines to `.htaccess`:

```
<Directory "/">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</Directory>
```

which gave a `500 error: internal server error`. Then I changed it to:

```
<Directory "/">
    AddCharset UTF-8 *
</Directory>
```

but had the same error. After I removed these lines, returning the file to the same as in the question, the problem was mysteriously solved.

I won't accept my answer, but wait for someone who can explain what happened.